# Django Python MySQL results manipulation

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a django setup that is working perfectly as follows:

The View:

```
def jsonfixture(request, soccerseason, fixturematchday):

data = StraightredFixture.objects.filter(soccerseason=soccerseason,fixturematchday=fixturematchday)

json_data = serializers.serialize('json', data, use_natural_foreign_keys=True)

return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
```

The Model:

```
class StraightredFixture(models.Model):
    fixtureid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    soccerseason = models.IntegerField(db_column='soccerSeason')  # Field name made lowercase.
    home_team = models.ForeignKey('straightred.StraightredTeam', db_column='hometeamid', related_name='home_fixtures')
    away_team = models.ForeignKey('straightred.StraightredTeam', db_column='awayteamid', related_name='away_fixtures')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'straightred_fixture'
```

This returns with each fixture with a home and an away team.  I.e

Team 1 V Team 4

Team 3 V Team 2

What I would like is to be able to manipulate the returned data and create a drop down list in a form as follows:

Team 1 Home V Team 4

Team 2 Away V Team 3

Team 3 Home V Team 2

Team 4 Away V Team 1

I hope this makes sense?  If you have any questions please let me know and I will respond right away.  Many thanks in advance for any help or advice you may be able to give.

Alan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following YouTube video walked me through the whole process and helped me understand the whole process:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gQe_8Q4YUpg&list=PLxxA5z-8B2xk4szCgFmgonNcCboyNneMD&index=13

Hope this helps someone in the future :)